# When debugging, how can I view the values of the variables in the last line of my code?

Tags: python

Usually, my debugging process involves placing `print()` statements in the appropriate places. However, there are times when it is necessary to see how the code functions in a fully-fledged debugging environment.
During step-by-step debugging, a feature arises - *it is not possible to view the values of variables from the current debugging line.* Often, the most significant variables receive their values at the end of the code snippet.
Of course, if one inserts an empty line or a comment line and attempts to set a **breakpoint**, this will not function. What are the effective ways to solve such a problem?

Most often I use the `print()` function to insert dummy lines under the **breakpoint** in the code. However, I noticed that if you forget to delete this code after debugging, it can affect the execution of the program. Recently, I have started using the `pass` statement instead of `print()`. This allows me to view the values of variables without affecting the execution of the code. Even if I accidentally leave the `pass` statement in the code, there are no consequences. Additionally, this approach does not spoil the aesthetic appearance of the code.

```
c = 0
while c > 0:
    c += 1 # now you can view the value of the variable
    pass   # breakpoint
```

Is it probably worth introducing a rule to add a `pass` at the end of loops, functions and other things? I am interested to hear your thoughts on this approach and how it could be applied in VS CODE to work more effectively with the debugger.

Comment: I'm puzzled about your question. You can simply put a breakpoint on a line to debug before it and do one step to be after it. Except you are talking about the very last line of your code, but then a variable value has no relevance anymore.

Comment: Try `pdb`. Import it then wherever you want the code to drop into an interactive (REPL) debugger, add `pdb.set_trace()` or if using 3.7+, `breakpoint()`. Once in debugger, you can use `n` (next) to resume running at next line after breakpoint, or use `s` to *step* through the code/function that is next in the debugger. You can inspect any variables in the debugger as you would in standard REPL environment, such as showing value of any variable.

Comment: I understand your frustration.  I often just add `print("hello")` or `math.sin(0)` just to have a place that I can set a breakpoint.

Comment: Put the breakpoint on the `c+=1` line. Then use the single-step command to go past it.